# wordpress multi language po file

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, translation, multilingual

i want to add 2 languages in my word press theme, i already have the translated **`.PO`** files ready but the theme uses only 1 of them,the default one. i tried to rename the desired language file from **`ar_EG.po`** to **`en_US.po`** which is my default language file and replaced it so that i can change my website language, it worked but i can't find anyway to make my website support 2 languages that people can switch from using a word press language plug-in.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to your_theme_setup function in functions.php

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'your_theme_name', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

$locale = get_locale();
$locale_file = get_template_directory() . "/languages/$locale.php";

if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) ) {
    require_once( $locale_file );
}
```

Comment: should i rename "locale_file" to my .PO files ar_EG.po and en_US.po?

Comment: Nope, you shouldn't. Create a folder named 'languages' inside your theme and put your ar_EG.po and en_US.po there. Also, make sure your wp-config.php file contains this: define ('WPLANG', 'ar_EG');

Comment: but how should users switch between both languages?